# Kotlin functional way

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I'm trying to perfect myself in Kotlin with functional programming. And then I did this:

I was tired of the way I write try - catch, and created the following function:

```
package com.learning.functionalway

fun <T> tryCatch(t: T?, excpetion: (Throwable)): T? = try {
    t
} catch (e: Exception) {
    throw excpetion
}
```

And I used it like this:

```
@Service
class ProductService(val repository: IProductRepository, val repositoryS: IStockRepository) : IService<Product, ProductModel> {

    override fun find(id: Long) = tryCatch(
            repository.find(id),
            DataNotFound("Product not found"))

other methods ..
}
```

And my exception that I deal in the "Exception Handler"

```
class DataNotFound(message: String?) : Exception(message) {
}
```

Is this a correct way I used to modify the way I use try - catch?
Or are there better ways to do it?

Comment: You can use this library https://github.com/kittinunf/Result you can capture your errors, transform and compose

Comment: I don't want to discourage you, but I don't think this does what you want: it evaluates the first param _before_ calling your function, so won't call your function at all if that throws an exception.  And even if it did, it'd always create an exception instance even if not used; and that wouldn't store anything about the original exception or where it was created, making debugging harder.  (When translating an exception to a new type, you'd usually give the original one as its cause, preserving all the info.)  You might work round these by passing lambdas, but it'd get unwieldy and confusing.

Comment: Not even. You encourage me to study more. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is not a "more functional" way of doing error handling but rather just arguably a slight improvement in try-catch syntax.

If you truly want to embrace functional programming, I'd recommend you to check out [Arrow](https://arrow-kt.io/). The standard Kotlin library is not enough for advanced functional programming concepts (such as error handling) and Arrow fills that gap.

You can read their [documentation](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/patterns/error_handling/) on how to do proper error handling.
If you fancy a talk about it, I'd recommend you to check out [this video](https://youtu.be/eNe5Nokrjdg?t=1620) (topic of error handling starts [here](https://youtu.be/eNe5Nokrjdg?t=1620)) which is about Kotlin and functional programming.

Comment: Everything is still very new and does not always make sense to me =). I'll watch the video and study Arrow. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: Your welcome. :) If you feel this answer answered your question, please accept it to mark your question as answered!

Answer (score 0):

One way to remake the try-catch syntax to make it more functional is like this:

```
sealed class Try<out Output> {
    class Some<Output>(val output: Output) : Try<Output>()
    class None(val exception: Exception) : Try<Nothing>()

    companion object {
        operator fun <Output> invoke(toTry: () -> Output) = try {
            Some(toTry())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            None(e)
        }
    }

    val value get() = when(this) {
        is Some -> output
        is None -> null
    }

    infix fun catch(onException: (Exception) -> Unit): Output? = when (this) {
        is Some -> output
        is None -> {
            onException(exception)
            null
        }
    }
}

class ProductService(val repository: IProductRepository, val repositoryS: IStockRepository) : IService<Product, ProductModel> {
    override fun find(id: Long): Product? = Try {
        repository.find(id)
    } catch { exception ->
        println("Error trying to get product $exception")
    }
    //other methods ..
}
```

The key advantage here is that unlike in the original syntax you can do things by parts. So if you have a lot of tries to do and want to handle all the results at the end, with this syntax you can.